помогите не образованному
только начал изучать С++, изучаю сам по видео урокам. не могу понять почему (пишет идентификатор "t" не определен)? не верный код?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");


    int nums[3];
    nums[0] = 56;
    nums[1] = 563;
    nums[2] = 2;
    cout << nums[2];

    float nums[3] = { 4,6,7 };

    for (int t = 0; t < 3; t++);
    cout << "El" << t << : << nums[t];

    return 0;


Потому что после for у вас сразу ;. Если подробнее, то переменная t будет доступна только внутри цикла for, который у вас отсутствует. Пока учитесь, не укорачивайте код и выделяйте блоки {}

спасибо. учу код по видео, и делал как он говорит. поэтому так и вишло

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");

    int t = 0;
    int nums[3];
    nums[0] = 56;
    nums[1] = 563;
    nums[2] = 2;
    cout << nums[2];

    float nums1[3] = {4, 6, 7};

    for (t = 0; t < 3; t++){
        cout << "El" << t << ":" << nums1[t];
    }
    return 0;
}

